# How to echo a variable from a variable

Tags: shell, unix, echo

I want to write a simple script where I assign a value of a variable as another variable. And then echo it. Something like this

```
abc=hi
hi=123
echo $abc
echo $hi
echo $(echo $abc)
```

For the third echo I want the desired output as "123" but that is not coming.

Comment: @fedorqui I think that we may both have overlooked the fact that the OP isn't necessarily using bash.

Comment: @TomFenech uhms, now I see the comment in your answer. Well, this is then definitely a duplicate (this is asked very often), only that it needs `eval`. I can reopen but then I won't be able to cast a close vote.

Comment: Please reopen and provide a solution. Indirect expansion is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use an indirect expansion:

```
$ abc=hi
$ hi=123
$ echo ${!abc}
123
```

In other shells, the alternative is to use `eval`:

```
$ eval echo \$$abc
123
```

Of course this comes with all the risks associated with using `eval`, for example:

```
$ abc="hi; echo oops"    
$ eval echo \$$abc
123
oops
```

Blindly evaluating strings as commands should be avoided wherever possible.